# Fragment Memory Leak during FragmentTransaction Android Studio

Tags: android-fragments, memory-leaks, weak-references, fragmenttransaction, leakcanary

I am using LeakCanary to monitor memory leaks in my mobile app in Android Studio. They were found in an activity that makes a FragmentTransaction operation with two Fragments. They are both instantiated with "new" keyword and in onCreate method another method is used "setFragment(fragment)" passing each Fragment as an argument depending on a bottomNavigationMenu selection.
And finally inside the setFragment(fragment) method is being used the "getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment).commit();" function.

This is the code:

```java
public class YouTubeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final NetworkFragment networkFragment = new NetworkFragment();
    private final MyListFragment myListFragment = new MyListFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_you_tube);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationMenu = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationMenu);

        setFragment(networkFragment);
        bottomNavigationMenu.setSelectedItemId(R.id.search_YouTube);
        bottomNavigationMenu.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            if(item.isChecked())
                return true;
            else{
                if(item.getItemId() == R.id.search_YouTube){
                    setFragment(networkFragment);
                    return true;
                }else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.search_my_list){
                    setFragment(myListFragment);
                    return true;
                }else{
                    setFragment(networkFragment);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar_3);
    }

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment){
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

How can I make this FragmentTransaction without leaking memory? I read about Weak Reference, is it an option?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of those awful memory leaks just by moving the instantiation of the two Fragments inside the NavigationItemSelectedListener and dropping the setFragment(fragment) method!

This tutorial helped me a lot:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPV8xA7m-iw&ab_channel=CodinginFlow (this guy is really talented!)